# Not able to see "OtherStateCode" field in Contact object

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, standard-field, scratch-org-definition-file, manifest

I'm retrieving the metadata from my Dev Hub org in the manifest to push it to a scratch org, but I'm getting the following error in some apex classes when pushing to default scratch org:

> No such column 'OtherStateCode' on entity 'Contact'. If you are
> attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c'

When I check in prod org (Dev Hub org) with a simple SOQL I'm able to see the field data, but if I do the same in my scratch org it throws the not such column error.

What I tried:

1. I added the field metadata specification in my manifest (package.xml):

> ```
> <types>
>     <members>Contact.OtherAddress</members>
>     <members>Contact.OtherStateCode</members>      
>     <name>CustomField</name>
> </types>
> ```
>
> Note: OtherStateCode it's a compound field of [OtherAddress](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm)

2. I retrieve the source in manifest from Org
3. Switch to my scratch org
4. Push to default scratch org (and got the errors)

I also tried to search for some special setting to activate the OtherStateCode field but there's no information about it, seems to be a simple field in Salesforce.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't retrieve and push this metadata; these are standard fields. You must turn on the `StateAndCountryPicklist` feature in your scratch org definition file:

```
  "features": [
    "StateAndCountryPicklist"
  ],
```

Comment: Thank you! , that was the solution